# How to apply only terraform changes via Github action pipeline

Tags: bash, github, terraform, github-actions

I have Github action created which is part of drift detection. The problem i see here even though there is not changes on terraform plan it's running the apply step, which I want to fix it.

```
     # An exit code of 0 indicated no changes, 1 a terraform failure, 2 there are pending changes.
     - name: terraform plan
       run:  |
         set +e
         terraform plan -detailed-exitcode -input=false -out=${{ github.sha }}.plan
         retVal=$?
         set -e
         if [ $retVal -eq 2 ]; then
           value=$(terraform show -json ${{ github.sha }}.plan | jq '.resource_changes[] | select((.type != "google_project_iam_binding") and (.change.actions | index("delete","update")))')
           if [ -z "${value}" ]; then
             exit 0
           fi
         fi
         exit $retVal

     - name: Notify via teams
       uses: dhollerbach/actions.send-message-to-ms-teams
       if: ${{ failure() }} 
         message: "Pipeline is failed "

     - name: terraform apply
       if: ${{ success() }}
       id: apply
       run: |
         terraform apply -auto-approve ${{ github.sha }}.plan
```

Comment: You could check for the output of the `terraform plan` for `"No changes. Your infrastructure matches the configuration.`.

Comment: It looks like you have a GitHub Actions pipeline set up for drift detection using Terraform, and you want to prevent the terraform apply step from running when there are no changes detected in the Terraform plan. You're currently using the detailed exit code from terraform plan to determine if there are pending changes.

The approach you've taken seems to be in the right direction.

Comment: as i said above in query, if no changes means it should skip the tf apply, and it's find any changes which is are matching with JQ filter only it has to run tf apply.

Answer (score 0):

You're currently using the detailed exit code from `terraform plan` to determine if there are pending changes.

The approach you've taken seems to be in the right direction. You can refine it a bit to ensure that the `terraform apply` step only runs when there are changes. Here's a modified version of your pipeline

```
name: Terraform Drift Detection

on:
  push:
    paths:
      - 'path/to/your/terraform/files/*'

jobs:
  detect_drift:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    
    steps:
      - name: Checkout code
        uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Set up Terraform
        uses: hashicorp/setup-terraform@v1
        with:
          terraform_version: <your_version_here>

      - name: Terraform init
        run: terraform init
      
      - name: Terraform plan
        id: plan
        run: |
          set +e
          terraform plan -detailed-exitcode -input=false -out=tfplan
          exit_code=$?
          set -e
          if [ $exit_code -eq 2 ]; then
            echo "There are pending changes."
            exit 0
          elif [ $exit_code -eq 0 ]; then
            echo "No changes detected in the Terraform plan."
            exit 0
          else
            echo "Terraform plan failed."
            exit 1
          fi

      - name: Notify failure
        if: ${{ failure() }}
        run: |
          echo "Pipeline failed."

      - name: Terraform apply
        if: steps.plan.outcome == 'success'
        run: terraform apply -auto-approve tfplan
```

Comment: if we add if and elif with exit 0, which mean both cased it's success. then it's going to apply it for both, I've tested it. didn't helped me to fix the issue.

as i said above in query, if no changes means it should skip the tf apply, and it's find any changes which is are matching with JQ filter only it has to run tf apply.

Answer (score 0):

Here is solution:

```
# An exit code of 0 indicated no changes, 1 a terraform failure, 2 there are pending changes.
- name: terraform plan
        id: plan
        run: |
          set +e
          terraform plan -detailed-exitcode -input=false -out=${{ github.sha }}.plan
          retVal=$?
          set -e
          if [ $retVal -eq 2 ]; then
            value=$(terraform show -json ${{ github.sha }}.plan | jq '.resource_changes[] | select((.type != "google_project_iam_binding") and (.change.actions | index("delete","update")))')
            if [ -z "${value}" ]; then
              echo "runapply=true" >> "$GITHUB_OUTPUT"
              exit 0
            fi
          fi
          exit $retVal

- name: terraform apply
        if:  ${{ success() && steps.plan.outputs.runapply == 'true' }}
        id: apply
        run: |
          terraform apply -auto-approve ${{ github.sha }}.plan
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a bit more elegant solution using Github Outputs.

`OtherConditions` in the workflows are any other logic that you may want to define like `!(failure)` etc.

```yaml
jobs:
  plan:
    name: Plan
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    outputs:
      exit-code: ${{ steps.plan.outputs.exitcode }}
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - uses: hashicorp/setup-terraform@v2
      - run: terraform init
      - name: terraform plan
        id: plan
        run: terraform plan -out terraform.tfplan -detailed-exitcode
  apply:
    if: ${{ OtherConditions && needs.plan.outputs.exit-code == 2 }}
    name: Apply
    needs: [plan]
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      [.....]
```

> Example is not a complete workflow but. is only about managing the logic to run apply stage when the plan has some changes/diff.